# Refresh Array of Images- Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to be able to clear the whole array of images with the click of a button and reload the array with updated values. I cannot get this to work by clearing the vertPanel. Can this be done by somehow resetting all the data? Any help would be appreciated.

```
var maxImgs = 6;      // Number of images in grid
var colUrl = 0;       // Column containing URL
var colName = 2;      // Column containing Name
var colAttr = 1;      // Column containing Attributes

function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Not Here');
var abspanel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','25px');
var grid = app.createGrid(8, 8);

var titleLabel = app.createLabel('Not Here');
titleLabel.setStyleAttribute('margin-left','85px');
titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("font-size", "135%");
titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold");
var insertlabel = app.createLabel('Which Schedule? (Insert Document Key)');
var inserttxtbox = app.createTextBox().setId('txtbox').setName('ttbox').setMaxLength(44);
var loadbtn = app.createButton('Load Pictures').setId('loadbtn');
var resetbtn = app.createButton('Refresh').setId('rbtn').setVisible(false);
var daylabel = app.createLabel('Select Day');
var mon = "P - Mon"
var tues = "P - Tues"
var wed = "P - Wed"
var thurs = "P - Thurs"
var fri = "P - Fri"
var dayListBox = app.createListBox().setWidth('140px').setId('day').setName('sday')
dayListBox.addItem(mon);
dayListBox.addItem(tues);
dayListBox.addItem(wed);
dayListBox.addItem(thurs);
dayListBox.addItem(fri);

// Borrowed from https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-    code-snippets/progress-indicators
var spinner = app.createImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/loading3T.gif')
                            .setVisible(false)
                            .setId('spinner');
// Client handler for loadbtn will start spinner when button clicked
// Server handler will stop spinner when done loading pictures
var loadSpinner = app.createClientHandler()
              .forTargets(spinner)
              .setVisible(true);
loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadSpinner);  

var loadhandler = app.createServerHandler('loadPics');
loadhandler.addCallbackElement(abspanel);
loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadhandler);

grid
.setWidget(1, 0, insertlabel)
.setWidget(1, 1, inserttxtbox)
.setWidget(2, 0, daylabel)
.setWidget(2, 1, dayListBox)
.setWidget(3, 1, loadbtn)
.setWidget(3, 2, resetbtn)
.setWidget(2, 2, spinner)
.setCellSpacing(5);

for (var img = 0, row = 5; img < maxImgs; img++) {
var image = app.createImage().setPixelSize(350, 350).setId('image' + img);
var imageName = app.createLabel('name').setId('name'+img);
var imageAttr = app.createLabel('attr').setId('attr'+img);
   var vertPan = app.createVerticalPanel().add(imageName).add(imageAttr).add(image).setStyleAttributes({'padding':'15px','borderStyle':'solid','border-radius':'15px','background':'silver'}).setVisible(false).setId('vertPanel'+img);
 grid.setWidget(row + Math.floor(img / 4), 1 + (img % 4), vertPan)
 }
 abspanel.add(titleLabel);
 abspanel.add(grid);
 app.add(abspanel);

 return app;
 }


 function loadPics(e) {
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ttbox);
 var list = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sday);
 var data = list.getRange("A121:C230").getValues().splice(1); // Get whole spreadsheet, without  headers

 for (var row = 0, img = 0; row < data.length && img < maxImgs; row++) {
 var rowData = data[row];
 if (rowData[0] != '') {
  var image = app.getElementById('image' + img);
  var imageName = app.getElementById('name'+img);
  var imageAttr = app.getElementById('attr'+img);
  var vertPan = app.getElementById('vertPanel'+img).setVisible(true);
  image.setUrl(rowData[colUrl])
       .setTitle(rowData[colName].toString() === '' ? 'image'+img : rowData[colName]);
  imageName.setText(rowData[colName]).setStyleAttribute("font-size", "150%");
  imageAttr.setText(rowData[colAttr]);
  img++;
  }
 }

 // Done loading, hide spinner
 app.getElementById('spinner').setVisible(false);
 return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better define another grid and add it to `abspanel`, In the handler function, call the image grid by ID and then use method `clear()`; to clear the grid. And then reconstruct it for new images.

I hope you get it what I am trying to say.

in `doGet()` function use

```
var imgGrid = app.createGrid(1,1).setId('imgGrid');
abspanel.add(imgGrid);
```

in your handler function use

```
var imgGrid = app.getElementById('imgGrid').clear();
imgGrid.resize(row, column);
//Now manipulate this grid to show new images
```

Comment: But what happens with the existing grid? I am looking for more of a Refresh button. Let me know.

Comment: You will recreate a grid of images every time you refresh. That is the best solution. Or if you are familiar with HTML and DOM, Javascript, I'll suggest you to migrate to the HtmlService in Apps Script

Comment: Sorry but I am stuck here... I added the grid to the abspanel but it comes up on top of the stackpanels. Also, when resizing how do you specify row, column?